# Run Cypress with specific Chrome version

Tags: cypress

I am looking for a possibility how to run Cypress with a specific versions of Chrome and not using Docker. From internal policy I am not allowed using Docker. We are using screenshot testing, therefore we need to use the same version of Chrome across the teams. And also in GitLab pipeline where Cypress tests run as well.

So I am facing a big issue with Chrome versions. I know that I can run Cypress command with a path to the browser. I was thinking that maybe I can download specific version from web such as chromium.cypress.io inside node_modules and run cypress with the path of the browser. But I need this to be automated during npm install.

I need to exclude Docker and manual install of the browser. Any ideas?

Comment: Which operating system are you using? The installation process for each OS will vary.

Comment: Windows but I would preffer cross-platform solution